# Browser ignoring css height & width

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm trying to make an iframe that will show the full page of the external site with a top div. The problem is all browsers are ignoring the width & height css.
This is what my css is

```
iframe {
position:fixed;  
width:100%; 
height:100%; 
border:none; 
margin:0; 
padding:0; 
overflow:hidden; 
z-index:999999;}
```

When you view the [site](http://hentaidoujinshi.com/8) it ignores the width and height which makes iframe not full screen. When I view the source in the browser the width & height are missing. Any fix to this?

Comment: maybe you forgot to close the css with curly braces?  "}"

Comment: just added the curly braces but still ignores the width/height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `vh` and `vw` uits for that. 1vw is 1% of viewport width, and 1vh is 1% of viewport height:

```
iframe {
position:fixed;  
width:100vw; 
height:100vh; 
border:none; 
margin:0; 
padding:0; 
overflow:hidden; 
z-index:999999;
}
```

By the way I looked at the site by link. It has a little broken style for iframe:

```
iframe {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 999999;
}
```

width value has no units, height is absent.

Following code works:

```
iframe {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 999999;
    height: 100%;
}
```